# Split value from field into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following data:

```
subitem, subitempart, subitemvalue
 'Badge", 'Issued to', 'abc'
 'Badge', 'Located at', 'bcd'
 'Badge, 'signed for', 'def'
 'key', 'number', '123'
 'key', 'Issued to', 'abc'
```

The subitempart names are from a separate table with two fields: [code] and [description].
A subitem can have 1 to 20 subitemparts, it varies per item.

My client wants to see this as followed:

```
[Subitem], [Issued to], [Located at], [Signed for], [Number]
'Badge'  , 'abc'      , 'bcd'       , 'def'       , NULL
'key'    , 'abc'      , NULL        , NULL        , '123'
```

So what I want to do, is put all subitemparts available to columns, then put the values in the right fields and then remove the columns that are empty on each row.

Is this possible in MS SQL and if yes, how?

thanks in advance for any help.

rg.
Eric

Comment: Hi Eric, try to give a look at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did in fact look at that page, but couldn't relate it to my specific problem.

Comment: Wait, I write you an example to show you how to relate it to your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to pivot your results.  One option is to use the `PIVOT` command.  I understand it better using `MAX` with `CASE` though:

```
select subitem,
   max(case when subitempart = 'Issued to' then subitemvalue end) IssuedTo,
   max(case when subitempart = 'Located at' then subitemvalue end) LocatedAt,
   max(case when subitempart = 'signed for' then subitemvalue end) SignedFor,
   max(case when subitempart = 'number' then subitemvalue end) number
from yourtable
group by subitem
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f73a/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that the table of subitemparts can be changed by adding new ones or deleting old ones. I don't want to edit the query each time that happens, so I need a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a pivot table, in sql it's not that difficult.

```
SELECT * FROM item
PIVOT (max(subitemvalue) 
    for subitempart in ([Issued to],[Located at],[signed to],[number])) as items
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make it more dynamic. I want the query also to work when a user adds a new subitempart.

Comment: it's a bit tricky check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/sql-server-pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation this is how it work, We use this method to do the dynamic pivot