# How do I get my rows of data organized into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which is pretty simple in that it just gets records from a table, the output is like this:

```
ID      group   StatusType      Task                DateAdministered        ScoreA  ScoreB
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-04-01 00:00:00.000         2       5
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-02 00:00:00.000         2       7
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-02 00:00:00.000         2       8
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-02 00:00:00.000         2       7
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-04-28 00:00:00.000         4       8
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-02 00:00:00.000         2       7
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-05-19 00:00:00.000         2       7
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-05-26 00:00:00.000         3       7
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-02 00:00:00.000         3       7
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-09 00:00:00.000         1       6
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-15 00:00:00.000         3       5
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-23 00:00:00.000         2       6
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-06-30 00:00:00.000         1       6
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-07-07 00:00:00.000         4       6
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-07-14 00:00:00.000         3       6
5199    MSP     Completed   Follow Up Contact   2011-07-21 00:00:00.000         2       7
```

What I need to do is re-organize the data into columns and not rows based on the date closest to the end of the month for a particular year of the DateAdministered for each ID, group, StatusType, and Task.  In other words, if there are two rows for a task in April, I will need the max date of those two and the report on ScoreA and ScoreB. The do the same for May, June, etc...

The end result should look like this:

```
ID      group       StatusType      Task            April Assessment    ScoreA  ScoreB  May Assessment  ScoreA  ScoreB  June Assessment ScoreA  ScoreB  July Assessment ScoreA  ScoreB
5199    MSP         Completed   Follow Up Contact       4/1/2011            2       5   5/26/2011           3       7   6/30/2011           1       6   7/21/2011           2       7
```

I have tried several things and I just am not sure of the best way to do this.  This almost seems like something for a pivot but don't need to SUM or ADD any columns, so I am not sure how that would work if I need a pivot.

Comment: It looks like you want the row closest to the beginning of the month, not the end.

Comment: Or did you just miss the row with ``2011-04-28``?

Comment: SQL, by itself, is not meant to allow the kind of dynamic column generation as you are looking for.  You mentioned pivots, if you are using a spreadsheet to display you have may have to use them.  If not it will depend on what type of GUI you are using to display this.

Comment: Unless you want to hardcode all the month column names, you will need a dynamic SQL statement. Look at this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/sql-server-pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I feel better knowing that I didn't miss something and this can't easily be done.  Ultimately this data will be sent in an excel spreadsheet but I was trying to get a query made and run it, then just save the results in excel.


acfrancis - yes, I missed that month.  I want the last one in each month.