# How do i join the rows into dynamic columns in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm sorry to post this, what i feel, almost duplicate. But i've tried the solutions i've found but haven't gotten it to work in my solution :(

This is how the SQL looks before i FUBARed it. This returns the data in a pretty good format. But i get duplicate rows with the same data except that the questions and answers are changed. I'd like that the Question would be the column name and the answer it's value.

```
SELECT c.*, sa.Question, sa.Answer
    FROM Customers as c, Surveys s, SurveyAnswers sa 
    WHERE c.OrderID IN(SELECT id FROM @orders)
        AND s.CustomerID = c.id
        AND sa.SurveyID = s.ID
```

My SQL is weak and i got to get this done asap :( The alternative is to do the more heavy lifting in the .net app but i'd be nice to get the data directly
Best regards,
Mikael

Comment: You're probably looking for something similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/sql-server-pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Bluefeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/sql-server-pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation) to accomplish a dynamic column pivot. (I've omitted your @orders filter for brevity):

```
DECLARE 
  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(sa.Question) 
            FROM SurveyAnswers sa
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT CustomerID, Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select 
                    c.ID as CustomerId, 
                    c.Name,
                    sa.Question, 
                    sa.Answer
                FROM Customers as c
                     INNER JOIN Surveys s ON s.CustomerID = c.id
                     INNER JOIN SurveyAnswers sa ON sa.SurveyID = s.ID
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(Answer)
                for Question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
 execute(@query);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/868dbc/1)