# How to not include a certain column during query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Thank you for the reply, but again im already using dynamic fields.

For example:

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(QuestionName as varchar) + ']', '[' + cast(QuestionName as varchar)+ ']')
FROM Answer A 
INNER JOIN Question Q ON A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
INNER JOIN Customer C ON A.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
GROUP BY Q.QuestionName

SET @columns = '[CustomerID],' + @columns

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)
SET @query = 'Some PIVOT query without aggregation'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

But i want to arrange the fields in @columns..i want 1 field to be 1st:

```
@columns = [f1],[f2],[f3].
```

What i want is like this:

```
@columns = [f2],[f1],[f3] :
```

Because one of the fetch data..is constant in my report..
and should be place in the beginning or the first row to be displayed.

Comment: You'll have to explicitly name the columns from `table1` instead of using `SELECT *`

Comment: Have a look at this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1712243/1423456

Comment: thank you Nicky for your reply, but i dont know the numbers of fields to be fetch,names of the fields, because it will depend on the user input.,

Comment: ow..i tried that already for the other reports.. but i want to know an easy and fast way.. thank you again

Comment: You should use sql dynamique, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/sql-server-pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation. He uses dynamic sql to generate the pivot and to generate the select. As it's dynamique you can always imagine to have a where cols not like f1 and add it yourself in the constructor