# PIVOT and TEMP TABLE

Tags: sql, pivot, temp

please can you help me put this script into a temp table. i have been working on this for hours and it keeps giving me errors.

```
    DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
    COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + CAST(expansion as varchar(max)) + ']',
    '[' + CAST(expansio

    n as varchar(max))+ ']')

INTO #temp
FROM (Select distinct expansion from #CD4_VL2) results


DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
select * from
(
select subjectID,expansion,printableValue1
from #CD4_VL2) as results


PIVOT

(MAX([printableValue1])
FOR [expansion] IN (
' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
)
) as PivotTable

--order by Performed_Date_And_Time desc
'

Execute(@PivotTableSQL )
```

Comment: What errors? If it's anything about syntax, have you *tried* `Print`ing the `@PivotTableSQL` instead of `Execute`ing it, and then examining the code?

Comment: Also (although I doubt this is the issue) you should be aware of [this warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: As per Damien's comment an alternative to using a mutating COALESCE to do `GROUP_CONCAT` is to use `STUFF` with xml, e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11985946/314291

Answer (score 0):

Because you've pivoted on the expansion columns, the respective values of `MAX(printableValue1)` will now be in columns with the names of the data in the `Expansion` column. Change this like so:

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Expansion1, Expansion2, Expansion3';

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @PivotTableSQL = 
N'select subjectID, ' + @PivotColumnHeaders 
+' from #CD4_VL2 
  PIVOT
(
  MAX([printableValue1])
  FOR [expansion] IN (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ')) x';

Execute(@PivotTableSQL);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d695/237)