# How to separate duplicate values for a specific row to another column - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a select statement which checks for a name and a score from two separated tables.
After select operation, I want second scores to be in another column for the same name.

Consider Score 69 will be next to 64 in another column.
How can I do that?

**Name** **Score**

```
John  64
Lisa  45
Jack  23
John  69
```

Requested:

**Name** **Score** **Score2**

John  64    69

Comment: which dbms mysql or oracle or  sql server?

Comment: You likely want to use `PIVOT` if it is SQL Server. Are the number of scores always 2? If it's fixed it pretty easy to do. If the number of scores is dynamic it is a little more involved.

Comment: It's SQL server 2008. Scores are dynamic and can be more then two. Not constant.

Comment: This is better to do in the application layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dynamic number of result columns, you'll almost certainly need to resort to dynamic SQL. Here's a take on this adapted from [Bluefeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation)

```
DECLARE 
  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(ScoreNum AS VARCHAR))
            FROM
            (
                SELECT Name, Score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Name ORDER BY Score ASC) AS ScoreNum
                FROM NameScore
            ) scores
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT Name, ' + @Cols
+ '
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Name ORDER BY Score ASC) AS ScoreNum
    FROM NameScore
) scores
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Score)
    FOR ScoreNum IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS p';
 execute(@query);
```

[With a sample SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3dec/1)

Noted that we had to run the query twice - once to see how many columns to create, and then again for the actual Pivot. For large amounts of data, you could DRY this up into a #Temp table @TableVar.

Comment: When run the query above, the output is:06974840 100 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 98 NULL 93 NULL NULL
12876324 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
14218452 100 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 100 NULL 96 NULL 90 NULL NULL
15133766 90 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 93 NULL 91 98 85 NULL 66 100 NULL
16278402 98 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 100 NULL 100 NULL 96 NULL 92 NULL NULL
19418462 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: You've seen the fiddle? Obviously unpopulated cells in the pivot will be null - only the 'widest' person will have all column values.

Comment: I will check and let you know the result, thank you.