# SQL Server pivot table to show as a row

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I created a query that shows the data as:

```
    accountNumber  fundid
--------------------------
1   238492348       1004
2   238492348       1005
3   238492348       1006
4   238492348       1007
5   238492348       1008
6   238492348       1009
7   238492348       1022
8   238492348       1339
```

I am trying to some how pivot the table in order to make the table look like this instead:

```
   accountNumber  adv1  adv2  adv3  adv4  adv5  adv6  adv7  adv8
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   238492348     1004  1005  1006  1007  1008  1009  1022  1339
```

Can someone assist me in how I can do this with SQL Server?

Everything I am reading wants me to do like a sum of the numbers or find an aggregate but I am just trying to rotate it and turn it into one row. The most columns it should ever have is up to `adv25`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In pivot command you always have to implement an aggregate function, even if there are not records to group

Comment: Did you google "SQL Server pivot without aggregate"?

Comment: @DavidBrierton what do you have and what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
--DROP TABLE #tmpS
CREATE TABLE #tmpS (accountNumber VARCHAR(25), fundid int)
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1004
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1005
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1006
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1007
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1008
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1009
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1022
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '238492348',1339

-- Consider adding more data here:
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '240000000',1337
INSERT INTO #tmpS SELECT '240000000',1337


SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT ColNbr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY accountNUmber ORDER BY fundid,accountNumber)
        ,accountNumber
        ,fundid
    FROM
      #tmpS a
   ) src PIVOT(MAX(src.fundid) FOR src.ColNbr IN(       [1]
                                           ,[2]
                                           ,[3]
                                           ,[4]
                                           ,[5]
                                           ,[6]
                                           ,[7]
                                           ,[8])) pvt
```

Comment: I'm here -- can you post the other query in this thread? Or start another question with it? I'll take a look

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chat feature - can you post the code here

Comment: I see the problem - you need dynamic columns. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation). I'll try to write it for your application in 1 min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185265/discussion-between-vic-street-and-david-brierton).